# Better way for custom range based histogram similar the one in Elastic Search on Clickhouse

Tags: clickhouse

I am looking for custom range based histogram similar the one in Elastic Search. [ref](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/8.12/search-aggregations-bucket-histogram-aggregation.html)
Unable to found similar one in ClickHouse.

So tried to compute the same as below. (Looking for better way if any)

query:

```
WITH
    0 AS offset,
    2 AS interval_val
SELECT
    bucket_id,
    --groupArray(number),
     arrayStringConcat([toString(bucket_id),toString(bucket_id+interval_val-1)],'-') bucket_start_end_range,
    count(number) count
FROM
(
    SELECT
        number,
        (floor((number - offset) / interval_val) * interval_val) + offset AS bucket_id
    FROM
    (
        SELECT number
        FROM system.numbers
        LIMIT 10
    )
)
GROUP BY bucket_id order by bucket_id
```

output:

```
┌─bucket_id─┬─bucket_start_end_range─┬─count─┐
│         0 │ 0-1                    │     2 │
│         2 │ 2-3                    │     2 │
│         4 │ 4-5                    │     2 │
│         6 │ 6-7                    │     2 │
│         8 │ 8-9                    │     2 │
└───────────┴────────────────────────┴───────┘
```

1. is there any other build-in function or short way that can achieve the above result.
2. is there any further optimisation can be done on the above query ?

Using CH 24.2.1.848

Comment: Seems pretty optimal and simple. Do you have any empirical evidence to suggest performance issues?

Comment: @gingerwizard we are currently comparing this quries result  with Elastic search results, i am newbie on both ES and CH. so i am not sure, what i am doing is correct way or not so raising queries to get better ways. Thanks for your time for analysing the query.